# Android: Need help in accurate position of shape drawing

Tags: android, canvas

In my Android project, I encountered some difficulties in the drawing code, so I made up a MCVE below to demonstrate the problem I have.

By running this example, and perform a touch in the screen, you can see two circles coming up.

You can see that the red one is positioned accurately and consistently around the point of touch.

For the green one, you can see that its position is somehow random on repeat touching of the screen.

The red circle is created using an `ImageView` with the source as `ball.xml`. For the green one, it is done by `Canvas.drawCircle()`.

So:

> How do I correct the code to make the red circle and green circle
>   appear at exactly the same spot on a touch, regardless of the resolution and dpi of the screen?

Also, btw, the 500X1000 dimension (`Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 1000)`)is just set arbitrarily, it should be according to the screen size of the device.

## MainActivity

```
package com.prime.testdraw;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView ivPhoto;
    FrameLayout fl;
    ImageView ivBall;
    private Canvas myCV;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ivPhoto = ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPhoto));
        fl = ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fl));
        ivBall = ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivBall));
        myCV = initDraw(ivPhoto);

        ivPhoto.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                myCV = initDraw(ivPhoto);
                ivBall.setX(motionEvent.getX() - ivBall.getWidth()/2);
                ivBall.setY(motionEvent.getY() - ivBall.getHeight()/2);
                Paint p = new Paint();
                p.setStrokeWidth(3);
                p.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                p.setTextSize(100);

                int radius = 40;
                p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                myCV.drawCircle(motionEvent.getX() - radius, motionEvent.getY() - radius, radius, p);
                ivPhoto.invalidate();

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    private Canvas initDraw(ImageView imageView) {

        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 1000, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        Canvas cv = new Canvas(bmp);

        imageView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp));
        imageView.invalidate();
        return cv;
    }

}
```

## activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fl">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ivPhoto"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="52dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivBall"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:src="@drawable/ball" />

</FrameLayout>
```

## ball.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="#FF0000" />

    <gradient android:startColor="#FFFF0000" android:endColor="#80FF0000"
        android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Canvas.drawCircle works with these parameters :

1. cx  float: The x-coordinate of the center of the cirle to be drawn
2. cy  float: The y-coordinate of the center of the cirle to be drawn
3. radius  float: The radius of the cirle to be drawn
4. paint   Paint: The paint used to draw the circle

Therefore instead of substracting the radius when calling it, simply call drawCircle directly :

```
myCV.drawCircle(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY(), radius, p);
```

Source : [Android Canvas doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawCircle(float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint))

Comment: Well that seems pretty straight forward for me.
When you receive a touch event, you move the red ball so that it's centered on the finger, which is fine. But the setX() and setY() don't work the same as the drawCircle. In the first one, the coordinates are for the top left corner, whereas the latter are for the center of the circle. Have you tested my code?